# Кака избавиться от квадратных скобок в словаре?

Tags: python

содержимое txt файла

```
ATM0 2020.200.12
ATM1 2019.200.06
ATM2 2020.200.17
ATM3 2020.200.16
ATM5 2020.200.16
ATM6 2017.200.09
```

```
with open('atm.txt') as f:
    content = list(filter(None, f.read().split()))
atm_dict = dict()
for element in content:
    if element[0].isalpha():
        key = element
        atm_dict.update({key: []})
    else:
        atm_dict[key].append(element)
print(atm_dict)
```

сейчас вывод такой:

```
{'ATM0': ['2020.200.12'], 'ATM1': ['2019.200.06'], 'ATM2': ['2020.200.17'], 'ATM3': ['2020.200.16'], 'ATM5': ['2020.200.16'], 'ATM6': ['2017.200.09']}
```

Comment: Зачем так сложно-то, весь код ужимается в одну строку `with open("atm.txt") as f: atm_dict = dict(x.strip().split(" ", 1) for x in f if x)`

Comment: @ andreymal  спасибо,  но я только учусь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
txt = 'ATM0 2020.200.12\n' \
      'ATM1 2019.200.06\n' \
      'ATM2 2020.200.17\n' \
      'ATM3 2020.200.16\n' \
      'ATM5 2020.200.16\n' \
      'ATM6 2017.200.09'
content = txt.splitlines()
# 1
atm_dict = dict()
for element in content:
    key, val = element.split()
    atm_dict[key] = val
print(atm_dict)

# 2
atm_dict = dict(element.split() for element in content)
print(atm_dict)
```

Comment: спасибо за предоставленные варианты!

Comment: Стоит иметь в виду, что «наивное» использование `.split()` сломается, если вдруг в строке окажется больше одного пробела